# Regex grouping: must start with /, optional group of characters alpha-numeric with forward slashes and total 1-255 characters

Tags: html, regex

I have an HTML5 `input` element with a `pattern` attribute. I'm having some trouble with an *optional group*.

- The (relative) URL *must* start with a forward slash (I have this working).
- The total (relative) URL may contain a total of up to 255 characters.
- All characters from 2-255 must be (lowercase) alpha-numeric or a forward slash.

Separately the forward slash regex works and the 2-255 part works for alpha-numeric and forward slashes. However I'm having trouble allowing both groups with the second group being *optional*.

What I have confirmed to work:

```
pattern="^\/"
pattern="[a-z0-9\/]"
```

However I can't determine how to allow the second group as an option (I've tried adding the `?` after the ending square bracket in example without luck).

I also am not sure how to combine the length (`{255,}`) bit to the total pattern expression.

How do I combine all three aspects of the regular expression?

Note: tags seem to be broken at the moment of posting this.

Comment: `pattern="/[a-z0-9/]{0,254}"`? You do not need `^` nor `$` in the `pattern` regex, by the way, it must match the whole string anyway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I thought we had to escape forward slashes? Hm, well that seems to work fine. Maybe the escapes kept it from working? Please post and I'll accept it.

Comment: `/` should only be escaped in regex literals where `/` is used as a delimiter char. `pattern` regexps are defined with literal strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
pattern="/[a-z0-9/]{0,254}"
```

You do not need `^` nor `$` in the `pattern` regex, by the way, it must match the whole string anyway, it will be parsed as `^(?:/[a-z0-9/]{0,254})$` pattern. That is, it will match a string that starts with `/` and then contains 0 to 254 lowercase ASCII letters, digits or slashes till the string end.

Note that `/` should only be escaped in regex literals where `/` is used as a delimiter char. `pattern` regexps are defined with literal strings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer *and* the clarifications. I've been modest at-best when it comes to regex, usually because people over-use it. HTML5's `pattern` attribute has made a very good case for it however.